# Jquery Blink when switching tabs

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui-tabs, jquery-tabs

I do not know if the issue is with jquery's load function or with jquery's tabs (or none of them) but my problem is that when switching between tab2 to tab1 (see code below) the tab content is cleared and then loaded again which causes a blink.  The data is loaded dynamically to the paragraph element in tab1 (id : the_paragraph) via the load function. the problem doesn't happen when switching from tab1 to tab2.

To reproduce: 
go to http://mumka12345.appspot.com/, hover mouse to tab2 and then back to tab1. I've placed 2 alerts to emphasize the issue.

This is my main page which has 2 tabs

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<script src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js'></script>
<script src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1/jquery-ui.min.js'></script>


<script>
    $(document).ready(function() 
    {
        $("#tabs").tabs({
        load: function(event, ui) 
        {
            $(ui.panel).delegate('a', 'click', function(event) 
            {
                $(ui.panel).load(this.href);
                event.preventDefault();
            });
        },
        event: "mouseover"
        });
    });
</script>

</head>

<body style="font-size:62.5%;">

<div id="tabs">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="/tab1"><span>tab1</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="/tab2"><span>tab2</span></a></li>        
    </ul>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

the server returns the following when requesting 'tab1':

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js'></script>
<script src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1/jquery-ui.min.js'></script>


<script>
    $(function() 
    {
        alert('ready');
        $("#the_paragraph").load("/fillParagraph" , function() 
        {
            alert('paragraph loaded');

        });
    });
</script>

</head>'


<body">    
<div id="container">
<p id="the_paragraph">
</p>    

</body>
</html>
```

the server returns the string 'Hello Tab2' when the client reques 'tab2'
the server returns the string 'Dynamic Fill' when the client reques 'fillParagraph'

Answer (score 0):

The response for tab one triggers a reload of jQuery and Jquery UI which certainly isn't helping.

Remove those script references from the response.

& try using console.log instead of alert.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response but the alerts have nothing to do with it.

Comment: the alerts suggestion was just to make your work flow a bit easier. My answer was regarding the reloading of jQuery & jQuery UI.

Also the page returned in your response makes yet another call to reload the content you desire. Why not just return the content the first time?